# Cloud end points is giving cached response

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I was using cloud endpoints services using javascript client library. I'm trying to get the data from the endpoints service but each time i'm requesting i'm getting different data which is cached by endpoints api i guess. Is there any way to make endpoints services not to cache data ? 
This is the sample responses i'm getting by hitting 
https://application.appspot.com/_ah/api/jobssyste/v1/servicetogetdata?accountNumber=8661234567

Here i'm getting responses on consecutive requests

```
Response of First Request :
{
 "monday": "02:30 PM,11:45 PM",
 "tuesday": "",
 "wednesday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "thursday": "07:45 AM,06:45 PM",
 "friday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "saturday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "sunday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "kind": "jobssystem#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"nXb0hCUd6fAuJMw6L-7tyR6KAhg/yP01K1lA_xkLIWbvG0lm7rzvQBU\""
}

Response of Second Request : 
{
 "monday": "02:30 PM,11:45 PM",
 "tuesday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "wednesday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "thursday": "07:45 AM,06:45 PM",
 "friday": "08:00 AM,05:00 PM",
 "saturday": "",
 "sunday": "",
 "kind": "jobssystem#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"nXb0hCUd6fAuJMw6L-7tyR6KAhg/KxBc34PXMgKGm7BmXfpXvGtWGbk\""
}
```

But firstResponse data is what i have in my DataStore. Couldn't able to find from where this cached data is coming from. Even i tried with mentioning not to cache in endpoints methods using.
@ApiMethodCacheControl(noCache=true,maxAge=0). Quick and accurate solution is appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to RFC2616 (specifically the part on [Idempotent Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)), identical `GET` requests for a URL should always return the same value.  Thus, caching of that value is perfectly acceptable.  Use `POST` if you're expecting dynamic data.

If that doesn't fix things, you'll have to do network traces (chrome://net-internals can show you what is going on) to see exactly what is being sent and received on the network.